# Keras Tensorflow fails to learn simple linear relationship

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I am fairly new to Tensorflow/Keras and am trying to set up an LSTM model. I have successfully run my code already, but my results have failed to give me meaningful results. I, therefore - as a test - let my LSTM network learn one of the features I am inputting. I am aware that the LSTM and relu use nonlinear relationships, however, I was still expecting the output to be somewhat similar to the input feature I was trying to learn which it is not at all.

I am using a modified version from what I learned on https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/

```py
feature_set = features.iloc[:-3,:].transpose() #23 features
target_set = features.iloc[-4:,:].transpose().iloc[:,0] #picking the 23rd feature
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(feature_set, target_set, test_size=0.2, shuffle=False, random_state=42)

rnn_units = 256
batch_size = 1
features_dim = 23
output = 1
def build_model(rnn_units):
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(rnn_units, batch_input_shape=[batch_size, None, features_dim], activation='relu'),
            tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1),
            tf.keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM(rnn_units,
                return_sequences=True,   
                stateful=True),
            tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1),
            tf.keras.layers.CuDNNLSTM(rnn_units,
                return_sequences=True,   
                stateful=True),            
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(output)
          ])
    return model

model = build_model(rnn_units=rnn_units)

model.compile(optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(), loss = tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error, metrics=['mse', 'mae', 'mape', 'cosine'])

reshape_train = int(X_train.values.shape[0]/batch_size)
reshape_test = int(X_test.values.shape[0]/batch_size)

history = model.fit(X_train.values[:reshape_train*batch_size].reshape(reshape_train*batch_size, -1, features_dim), y_train.values[:reshape_train*batch_size].reshape(reshape_train*batch_size, -1, output), epochs=EPOCHS, batch_size=batch_size, validation_data=(X_test.values[:reshape_test*batch_size].reshape(reshape_test*batch_size, 1, features_dim), y_test.values[:reshape_test*batch_size].reshape(reshape_test*batch_size, 1, output)), callbacks=[checkpoint_callback,tensorboard])
```

As you can see I am inputting a feature set of 23 values and am trying to learn the 23rd feature. I am using 256 nodes in every layer, with one Dense layout at the beginning and at the end and 2 LSTM layers followed by Dropout layers.

I am using mean-square as it is supposed to be a regression on time series data.

This is, for instance, one run of my training:

```py
Epoch 5/5
10329/10329 [==============================] - 93s 9ms/sample - loss: 0.0182 - mean_squared_error: 0.0182 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0424 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 94.4916 - cosine_proximity: -0.9032 - val_loss: 0.0193 - val_mean_squared_error: 0.0193 - val_mean_absolute_error: 0.0438 - val_mean_absolute_percentage_error: 58.2152 - val_cosine_proximity: -0.9443
```

And when I run

```py
result = model.predict(feature_set.values.reshape(-1, 1, features_dim))

feature_set.transpose().append(pd.DataFrame(result.reshape(-1), columns = ['Prediction 5min']).set_index(features.columns).transpose()).transpose()
```

I get for instance

```py
2019-03-04 01:00:00 82.0105414589   0.0704929618    -0.1165011768   -0.3369084807   -1.8137642288   -0.2780955060   -4.3090711538   6.2721520391    9.5553857757    -1.2900340169   ... -29.8867675862  1.9178869544    -1.4765772054   1.0000000000    0.0000000000    0.0000000000    0.0000000000    0.0080950060    -0.3594492457   0.0056902645
```

where the last 2 values should be equal but they are

```py
-0.3594492457   0.0056902645
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong in my model? Can I use LSTM to learn such relationships?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A few issues:

Typically, LSTM layers go at the start, followed by a few dense layers.

Also, the LSTM layer before the dense layer needs to have return_sequence set to False.

However, I'm not sure that they are the reason to cause this problem, I'm just pointing out the problems. I think it is more likely to be the dataset that is the issue, you should check if the dataset has the pattern.